# Rewrite sub-domain url on web.config

Tags: url, web-config, query-string, subdomain, url-rewriting

In web.config, i want to re-write url of sub-domain.

http://m.mySite.com/listing-50.php

to

http://m.mySite.com/listing.php?id=50

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be useful to familiarize yourself with [Url Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite). With the right regex, you should be able to manage what you are looking for.